# Возраст по дате рождения javascript

Tags: javascript

Как вычислить возраст человека лет и месяцев по дате рождения ?

Есть ли простая функция у javascript ?

Comment: берёшь сегодняшнюю дату вычитаешь дату рождения = получаешь сколько человеку лет, месяцев, недель, дней, часов, секунд, миллисекунд

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, как ты переведешь полученные миллисекунды после вычитания дат в года и тд?

Comment: @Grundy переведу из миллисекунд в секунды, из секунд в минуты из минут в часы и т.д.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, а в года как будешь переводить? :) и в месяцы тоже интересно :)

Comment: @Grundy разделю полученную дату на количество миллисекунд, которые равны году

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, а сколько миллисекунд в году? :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107731/discussion-between---and-grundy).